# Can I use both px and em in the same style sheet?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I wanted to know If I can use both px and em in the same CSS file (for same tags/class). What I mean by this is that, can I have something like this : -

```
body{
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-size: 0.625em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: #333333;
    background: #E0E0E0;
}
```

My objective is to convert a very big CSS file that supports 'em' so that the user can decide the font size they would like to use. But my problem is the well documented issue with 'em' - the nested tags get affected.

I sought for help by using 'rem' in certain places instead of 'em'. Though it helped a bit, I lost the entire structure of the webpage.

I would like to keep the exact same font size in my webpage and still support the user wanting to change font size.

I am using jQuery to add a class to the body tag that would contain a specified font size and everything else should be scalable.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not really the question, but I came here looking for another answer, so I will post it anyway. (About your question, obviously it makes no sense to define the same property twice with different units, but check the other answers for that.)

But yes you can use em and px in the same style sheet, and you can use em and px even *in the same property*!

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footnote {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
input {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
.input-replace {
    padding: calc(0.5em - 3px);
    border: 4px solid #eee;
}
```

When you use `calc()` you can make sure the size of the two elements is always exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

### To address your sample css...

**You can mix px and em (and percentage) to your heart's content.** This is fine:

```
body{
    font-size: 10px; 
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

**You cannot define the same css property twice.** Well, technically you can, but only one of them will be applied. So this is broken:

```
body{
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-size: 0.625em;
}
```

But it has nothing to do with mixing px and em. This is also broken:

```
body{
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

### The good news is you're on the right track...

- Define some top level container, or the body, with font-size in pixels.
- Define every sub node with font-size in em.
- Use javascript to change the top level container's font-size.

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/pn1tyaxb/

Notice that the buttons, and indeed anything outside of the top level container you've chosen, will not be affected by rescaling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion pabo! I will try this out and see if this works. My guess is it should. Also, do you know how I can address the 'li' tags as this is the one that is nested for me and 'em' doesnt work well here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `em` units for any text (or other elements) that you want to scale based off the user's selection. And use `rem` units for things you want to stay the same size.

[DEMO EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1SIJf?p=preview)

---

**CSS:** The REM units will be based off this value (base 10 for easy calc)

```
html { font-size:10px; }
```

**HTML:** User can select what size they want the page font to be

```
<select id="sizeSelector">
  <option value="10px">Extra Small</option>
  <option value="12px">Small</option>
  <option value="14px">Normal</option>
  <option value="16px">Large</option>
  <option value="18px">Extra Large</option>
</select>
```

**JS:** Create a jQuery function bound to the select box that modifies the `<body>`font-size, thus changing your `em` based declarations:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sizeSelector").change(function(e) {
    $("body").css('fontSize', e.target.value);
  });

  // initialize font size for first page load
  $("#sizeSelector").prop("selectedIndex", 2).trigger('change');
});
```

---

**Updated:** Code is no longer dependent on classes

Comment: Remember that anything you DON'T want to change should be defined in `rem` units.

Comment: Thanks J.C. I also wanted to know what your approach would be to tackle 'rem' for old browsers. I believe old browsers do not support the 'rem' unit. So do you suggest me to have 'px' in that case ?

Comment: Define both units for best browser support. You'll define the `px` value first, then it's `rem` version after it like this `font-size:10px; font-size:1rem;`. New browsers will use the `rem` version since its the last one declared, and old browsers will ignore 'rem' and fallback to the `px` declaration. If you are using LESS or SASS here is an awesome tut: http://drublic.de/blog/rem-fallback-sass-less/

Answer (score 0):

**You cant define in the same css.But you can define like this.**

```
.input {
     width:100px;
    }



 <input width:0.1em;>
```